# Why has this question not been closed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

This is the question I am referring to: [Feasible level for Yuffie to be at in order to attempt Godo's pagoda](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127707/feasible-level-for-yuffie-to-be-at-in-order-to-attempt-godos-pagoda)

I cannot see any reason (other than it is FF7) that this question has been so well received. There is no definite answer to the exact question, and I feel like it should be closed as "primarily opinion based" because everybody will have their own opinion of what the correct answer is, or "too broad" because there are so many many different factors to consider when providing an answer.

So why has this been allowed? Is this a fair question to ask?

Comment: In my opinion it's because people are giving objective reasons and some general tips.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: Yeah, but good answer don't make the question any better

Comment: [You'll want to read this.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) Subjectivity isn't inherently bad. What's bad is a question where all answers are *inherently equivalent* and don't need to be supported by facts.

Comment: Ironically, this meta has probably resulted in more attention and more upvotes on that question than it otherwise would have gotten.

Answer (score 10):

This is not an opinion based question at all, really. Determining potential for success is a fairly objective activity. You can use math and game mechanics to determine if you're too low a level to complete something. If you want the "most efficient" level for completing something, you'll want the lowest level where success is still a likely option, again based on math and game mechanics.

The current question is objectively answerable, and *not* opinion based.

For clarification, a question asking for opinions would be something like "What materia is best?" or "Which character is best?" These questions are bad because they don't really require thought, and there is no single objective answer. All the materia and all the characters are generally worthwhile, and good in different circumstances. If you narrow down your question, like "Which character is best for casting offensive magic?", then it becomes a useful question again, because it can be answered objectively. Asking "Which strategy is best for this specific scenario?" is, similarly, a good question, and that's what we have here. A good answer will include sound reasoning backing up the strategy.

That said, this still isn't a terribly good question for other reasons. It could be better worded as "What is a good strategy for beating Godo's Pagoda as early as possible?" or even "What is a good strategy for beating Godo's Pagoda?" without a level restriction. This makes the question easier to approach for an answer, more generally useful, and a good answer will still give all the information requested in the original question as asked.

Comment: This also seems like a reasonable example of "Good Subjective/Bad Subjective."

Comment: So what is the answer to the question "Feasible level for Yuffie"? because the given answer does not mention a level

Comment: @musefan Just because the existing answer doesn't answer a question doesn't mean it's off topic as a question. I don't know the answer in this case, just that it's possible to determine.

Comment: @StrixVaria: But it is not possible to determine it. For example, and these are just made up numbers but, one answer could say "Lvl 25 with KOR materia", another answer could say "Level 35 without KOR materia", another answer could say "Level 15 if you farm power/defense/magic sources". Point is, there isn't even a 5 level range you could estimate to be the correct answer to the question, let alone a specific minimum. The answer is dependent on way too many other factors

Comment: @musefan How many factors?  Would it require a book to answer the question for all situations?  If so, it would be too broad, but I believe this is objective enough to answer without too much of a problem.

Comment: @musefan The ban on opinion-based questions isn't ideological, it's practical. The point is to avoid having questions that are only 'answerable' by a slew of answers of the form "You should do it like X" and "My favourite Y is Z". As you can see, this question is *not* attracting such answers at all. Since the question is not displaying the problems that are necessarily caused by opinion-based questions, it therefore must not be inherently opinion-based. QED.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I only put "opinion based" in my title as I wasn't permitted to just have "Why is the question allowed?" on it's own. My question mentions "too broad" being a potential too (which is probably the more appropriate one anyway)